# init Uart pins as PWM out

Tags: uart, pwm, adafruit-circuitpython

Using circuitPython on Feather m0 basic, I'm unable to use Board pins 10 and 11 as PWM outs at the same time.

They both work with `pwmio.PWMOut()` separately, but If I try to initialize both of them at the same time the program crashes.

I found that these are the UART pins. Is there a way to configure these pins to both be PWM outs at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly which pins you are referring to but this looks fine on CircuitPython `6.0.1` on an [Adafruit Feather M0 Bluefruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-bluefruit-le), an example from REPL:

```
Adafruit CircuitPython 6.0.1 on 2020-12-28; Adafruit Feather M0 Adalogger with samd21g18
>>>
>>> import boardpulseio
>>> pwm_d11 = pulseio.PWMOut(board.D11)
>>> pwm_d12 = pulseio.PWMOut(board.D12)
>>> pwm_d11.duty_cycle = 10000
>>> pwm_d11.duty_cycle = 12000
>>> pwm_d12.duty_cycle = 40000
>>> pwm_d12.duty_cycle = 38000
>>> pwm_tx = pulseio.PWMOut(board.TX)
>>> pwm_rx = pulseio.PWMOut(board.RX)
>>> pwm_tx.duty_cycle = 12345
>>> pwm_rx.duty_cycle = 54321
```

How does yours differ from that? What's the error message?

Are you using `variable_frequency` or specifying different frequencies? That causes more hardware counters to be used under the covers.